# MXunit testing for type of boolean

Tags: coldfusion, mxunit

I think I need to test for a return type of boolean as a first test.
How would I do this?

for any method that returns a boolean such as

```
public boolean function isValid( required numeric id ) {
    // returns 'true' if data is valid, 'false' if data is not valid
}
```

there are; assertIsQuery and assertIsStruct ... I think I'm looking for something like assertIsBoolean and since there isn't that method, the closest is

```
assertIsTypeOf
```

but I do not know what syntax to use to test boolean 'type' - and is seems as though test assertTrue or assertFalse are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Well are you testing whether *it's a boolean*, or whether it's `true` or `false`? it's far more common to be testing it's the latter, in which case you'd use `assertTrue()` or `assertFalse()` as appropriate.

If you really need to test whether it's a boolean irrespective of value, then just use `isBoolean()` in an `assertTrue()`:

```
assertTrue(isBoolean(result));
```

BTW, it sounds like you're just starting out with testing, if so: it's perhaps best to not use MXUnit which is pretty much a dead project. Use [TestBox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/testbox) instead. It is actively supported, is MXUnit-compatible to facilitate migration away from xUnit style testing, and leverages more modern approaches to writing tests.

Comment: thanks adam, Yes, Im trying to 'formalize' my unit testing with tools, I've always written homegrown test pages as 'pseudo-suites' - I'll look into testBox. Can you be kind enough to mention a few approaches "by name", if xUnit type testing is passe. Thx again

Comment: Well TestBox will use the notion of BDD-style tests, but I think that's mostly a misnomer (although one that has industry traction) and I generally try to avoid the term. In the CFML world there's only really the options of xUnit and TestBox's "BDD style". If you want to ask questions, can I recommend you join the CFML Slack Channel (subscription links in this blog article: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2015/06/cfml-slack.html. There is a subchannel there for TestBox.